# Git how to solve This branch is X commits ahead, X commits behind master

Tags: git

I have a `Git` repo with a `dev` and a `master` branch. I'm adding new stuff on the dev branch and do commit those. So far so good, but I get the info that

```
This branch is 5 commits ahead, 12 commits behind master.
```

So what am I supposed to do now?

Basically I want to merge the master into the dev branch without losing the newly added changes to the dev branch, and then merge all changes into the master branch.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: I would rebase on the remote master by doing a fast forward only merge `git fetch` and `git merge --ff-only origin/master`. and of course fixing any conflicts as they arise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As with most things in git you a have a couple options

Merge master into your dev branch

```
git fetch origin master   
git checkout dev
git merge origin/master
git checkout master
git merge dev
```

Rebase dev ontop of current master

```
git fetch origin master
git checkout dev
git rebase origin/master
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff dev
```

The rebase will look cleaner in your history.

Comment: No pull / fetch? How will that help?

Comment: I added a fetch. Didn't think it was necessary since git already knew it was behind/ahead.

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon Should my starting point be the master branch? I mean before I run the commands you listed in your answer?

Comment: The second command "git checkout dev" starts you on the dev branch. Doesn't matter where you are before that.

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon ah ok good, but still `git fetch master`?

Comment: git fetch doesn't do anything to your current checkout. It grabs the latest changes from your remote and makes them available locally. You have to do a merge after a fetch to make any local changes. A git pull is a combination of a fetch and a merge.

Comment: `git fetch master` is not valid; if you are specifying a branch name you need to also specify the remote. `git fetch origin master`, `git fetch origin`, or just simply `git fetch` (the rest will be filled in from config).